# After Win 10 April Update Visual Studios custom applications won't Open

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, windows-10

I'm having a rather interesting/frustrating problem after doing the April Update to our companies, Windows 10 Pro x64bit, Opti5050 machines. **We have a number of applications built with Visual Studio 2012 (not Windows Store apps) we rely on that were working before the update, however after, they simply just won't open. There is no error message at all, nothing other then a spinning loading circle, then it stops and nothing happens**.

It also appeared to impact our office 365 excel, which couldn't open saved files, however, this was fixed with the newest version of .net. So I feel it could still be a .net issue

Some things I've tried,

- Re/Downloading and trying all versions of .net/crystal reports our app uses.
- Compatibility Troubleshoot/Run as if on win 7, 8, etc.../Properties of app settings
- Security/Permissions User Settings
- Running from the command line to see if there are any error messages, (none, the apps executable is just not running at all.)
- Going into the Features turn on or off and toggling all the .NET versions on.
- Rolling back the update, (seemed whatever changed is staying)
- Updating the apps in visual studios to run on all machines, and with an install package, it will run with a slew of other errors, including crystal reports which doesn't seem to be an easy fix. This also didn't work for fixing every visual studios application, some still just do nothing when clicked. (not the preferable route.)

Other info:

- Applications worked fine after the update on a win 7 PC that is using the free upgrade to win 10, and is current on all updates.
- Applications were made with vb.net and visual studios 2012. No issues before the update.

Comment: Have you tried to re-register the application for all the users? I had the same but for some preinstalled applications from MS.

Comment: Yes, didn't work, I did this through running powershell as an Admin, I thought I might have been missing/messed something up, since initially when the computers were new I ran a cmd to remove all the Microsoft junk apps, since these PC's were for an office.

Comment: It's weird that this happens on all of the machines - even after rolling back the changes.  Is it possible security software or group policies could be interfering?

Comment: I checked the policies and security of the app, but if there is something deeper, say in the registry, and not domain related, I wouldn't know where to look... I really think it's a missing plugin/.net/or crystal report problem, but I'm at a loss as I feel I've tried them all

Comment: @Vermonster There are 3 commands about Windows 10 Apps installation/information. One is Get-AppxPackage | Display Name to see which apps are installed on the user side, then there is Get-AppxPackage -All Users, to see which applications are installed for all users and last one, Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online to see which applications are provisioned. Which one did you use to re-register the applications?

Comment: Those commands just tell me what is/isn't installed? I think the problem here is that the applications not working are ones we made in-house with visual studios and we just share the executable over network folders. They aren't really registered in the same way an official Microsoft app is. When I say I ran the PS cmd's I mean I ran this, Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}, In case when I deleted their native junk apps long ago, something important got removed too.

Comment: I had this happen on one of the insider builds. I fiixed it by doing an "in-place-upgrade" installation and by uninstalling a package that relied on the `VDD2HookKMode` driver that ships with Barco Clickshare and a few other packages. See: https://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2018/03/fixing-edge-start-menu-and-cortana.html

Comment: @jessehouwing The problem in that link sounds very different, can you elaborate anymore? Again these are personally made vb.net coded visual studio applications, not Microsoft official applications, or from any store. There are no error messages, crashes, or slowness, simply executables that won't run or start.

Comment: In that case please reword your question and remove the ambiguous word "apps". All the `AppxPackage` suggestions hint towards store apps too. I'd try the in-place upgrade. Just create an ISO of the Windows 10 1803 build and launch the installer from the desktop of the machine. Choose to keep everything and it will retain all your apps, settings and applications.

Comment: Windows 10 also ipgrades the .NET framework to 4.7.2, which may have caused your applications to break. There is noway to downgrade to a lower version. If you applications rely on .NET 4, they may be impacted. Visual Studio 2012 support has ended, Worst case the proper solution would be to upgrade the projects to Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 retarget to .NET 4.7.2 and fix any issues that come from it. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#Overview

Comment: Also try a clean install and then installing these business ciritcal applciations. That ensures that no upgrade logic in the installer will break you. You can try opening a support ticket, but given the current support status of the tooling you rely on, I suppose that may be a pretty expesive option, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a shot

Comment: Have you tried rolling back the Windows Update that created the problem? I know it doesn't solve the problem, but it buys time.  Then you can clone the computer to a VM and work on solving it there without having a dev machine down.

Comment: Yeah I'm testing off a clone now that was made before the update. But it seems the new 4.7.2.net framework from the update stays on roll backs. So I have to use my clone to make 60 pc's if I go that route... a ton of work, so trying to avoid that and just get these applications working. Security and care free auto updating is the goal so, at this point I've gone on to just updating the apps in Visual Studios and trying to solve the crystal report errors... So far they are working again but have errors on certain features. If there is a way to talk in chat maybe you can help me solve them.